# How to use COM Interop references in Cake?

Tags: c#, cakebuild

We have a some project with the COM Interop references (is static linked to the project).
I created the cake-build script with the reference to this DLL. 
On the processing:

```
Task("Build").Does(()=>
{
    NuGetRestore(solutionFile);
    MSBuild(solutionFile);
});
```

build script has error that my DLL library has a wrong format.
Does cake support the COM references? Maybe I need to do something?

**Upd.** When I build script without references to COM dll, the compiler throws error CS0246 that classes from this DLL doesn't found and that I missing the reference to it.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your asking about, are you trying to use a com dll within the build script or withing the project you're building?

Comment: This COM library being used successfully in the project. The problem occurs when I try to build my project with cake. In the script I added this library with the #r directive, and cake doesn't understand this dll.

Comment: If you are not using the COM dll in your build script, there is no need to reference it using the `#r` directive. It can still be part of your project without including it in the build script.

Comment: But when I build script without this references, the compiler throws error CS0246 that classes from this DLL doesn't found and that I missing the reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was when we do a build as 'Any CPU'. Changed to 'x86' and dependencies been resolved (`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6`)